# Input element has unexpected wrapping behavior with bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, grid

I was writing a sidebar for an email client which I had mostly completed, but when I tried to put content in the main body area (another row) I noticed that it would wrap if the screen got smaller when it shouldn't. I can't seem to figure out what is causing this behavior.

```css
body {
  background-color: WhiteSmoke;
}

nav {
  //  border: solid 1px blue;
  //  background-color: WhiteSmoke;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  //  background-color: yellow;
}

div.container {
  //  background-color: blue;
}

span {
  //  background-color: purple;
}

li {
  //  background-color: lightblue;
}

ul>div>li span.fa-caret-right {
  color: green;
}

ul>div>li span.fa-flushed {
  color: green;
}

ul>div>li span.fa-trash {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./sidebar.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <nav class="w-350">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <img class="img-fluid col-3" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/php/php_PNG44.png">
          <div class="row">
            <span class="col-8">Firstname Last</span>
            <p class="col-8">name@email.com</p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <ul>
          <div>
            <button type="button" class="col-9 btn btn-primary">Compose</button>
            <li><span class="col-1 fas fa-caret-right p-3"></span><a class="col-11" href="#">Inbox</a></li>
            <li><span class="col-1 fas fa-caret-right p-3"></span><a class="col-11" href="#">drafts</a></li>
            <li><span class="col-1 fas fa-caret-right p-3"></span><a class="col-11" href="#">sent</a></li>
            <li><span class="col-1 fas fa-flushed p-3"></span><a class="col-11" href="#">spam</a></li>
            <li><span class="col-1 fas fa-trash p-3"></span><a class="col-11" href="#">trash</a></li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </nav>

        <input type="text" class="col-8 form-control" placeholder="Search">
        <span class="fas fa-caret-left"></span>
        <span class="fas fa-backward"></span>
        <span class="fas fa-caret-right"></span>
        <span class="fas fa-times"></span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

A lot of the CSS has been commented out. This just happened through trial and error. All the commented out code will be removed after I get the template for the client working. Infact most of the styling doesn't work at the moment due to changes I made in the html, but I'm including the CSS anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-12">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/php/php_PNG44.png">
        <div>
          <span class="">Firstname Last</span>
           <p class="">name@email.com</p>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <div>
            <button type="button" class="col-9 btn btn-primary">Compose</button>
            <li><span class="col-1 fas fa-caret-right p-3"></span><a class="col-11" href="#">Inbox</a></li>
            <li><span class="col-1 fas fa-caret-right p-3"></span><a class="col-11" href="#">drafts</a></li>
            <li><span class="col-1 fas fa-caret-right p-3"></span><a class="col-11" href="#">sent</a></li>
            <li><span class="col-1 fas fa-flushed p-3"></span><a class="col-11" href="#">spam</a></li>
            <li><span class="col-1 fas fa-trash p-3"></span><a class="col-11" href="#">trash</a></li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-lg-8 col-12">
        <p>
          What is Lorem Ipsum?
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It was happening because of the bootstrap classes was not used properly. Check this bin, hope it'd help https://jsbin.com/dedikiredo/edit?html

Comment: This removes the fixed width from the sidebar. It also makes the avatar photo (php) too big. The name and email don't stay to the right of the avatar photo.

Comment: give that avatar a fixed width, also you can change width of the classes like .col-md-4 to .col-md-2 like this. Or you can do custom code and keep that sidebar fixed on left